# Please merge the accounts greg-grossmeier and user11778

Tags: support, status-completed

Both are associated with OpenIDs I own, one from creativecommons.net (greg-grossmeier) and one from launchpad.net (user11778).

Please merge them into the greg-grossmeier account (this one).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's fine. They should have been merged now and the old account shouldn't show on the site.